# Maven property current user name?

Tags: java, maven

Is there any maven property to get the user name of the user that runs maven (windows and linux)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can just use System Properties, here's the [Overview of standard Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).

In your case, `user.name` is what you want, use the `${}` syntax:

```
<someProperty>
${user.name}
</someProperty>
```

Comment: Works very well ... e. g. Windows 10 with maven SCM cvs native client (analog CVS-NT) `<connectionUrl>scm:cvs:pserver:${user.name}@cvs-server-host-name:/cvs-repository</connectionUrl>` [CVS-Native cvs-1-11-22] Client](http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/stable/x86-woe/)

Comment: Somethink about the SCM-Maven-Plugin [SCM CVS HowTo] (https://maven.apache.org/scm/cvs.html)