# Get UID in a maven variable?

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

I can use the current username in a `pom.xml`-file with `${user.name}`, but is there a way to get the uid (userid)?

I use `exec-maven-plugin` and add arguments to a execution. I've tried different things (`${env.UID}`, `${user.id}`, `$UID`), but neither work.

I need it to start a process in docker that writes files to a shared directory. If I don't start with the `-u`-parameter all files will belong to `root`.
The configuration is like:

```xml
<configuration>
  <executable>docker</executable>
  <arguments>
    <argument>run</argument>
    <argument>-u</argument>
    <argument>$UID</argument>
    <argument>...</argument>
  </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I checked with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317609/maven-overview-for-the-values-of-maven-properties, there seems not to be a value representing the UID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I intended to write a maven plugin to provide the property `user.id` but then I did not find a way to get the userid with standard java methods.
There are two projects ([Java Native Access](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/)) to have direct access to native informations, but so far I haven't found a way to get the `UID`.

I fixed my problem by adding a `umask`-call in my Dockerfile. I strongly recomend to use a solution that does not requires the user-id within maven.

But working on the issue I created a [solution](https://github.com/rynr/user-id-maven-plugin) for others that really need this. It takes the `user.name`-property from the system-properties and then opens the `passwd`-file to search for the uid. Of course this will only work for unix-like systems and it couples the build directly with your environment, so use this solution wisely (idealy not at all).
To use my solution, add this to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <!-- Plugin only works with unix-like environments, please use it wisely! -->
  <groupId>org.rjung.util</groupId>
  <artifactId>user-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>user-id</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand you correctly, does this not work?

```
${user.name}
```

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227720/6737860).

Comment: Agreed. Quoted from ``Docker run --help`` : `-u, --user                      Username or UID (format: <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])`

Comment: I only can use the username if the user is created in the image. I also cannot map the internal UID to the external UID through the shared filesystem. The main goal is to have the files created in docker to belong to the user outside of docker. It says in the documentation: The image developer can create additional users. Those users are accessible by name. When passing a numeric ID, the user does not have to exist in the container.